# Javascript Email Validation Error (Works in ASP.Net not in ASP.Net MVC)

Tags: javascript, regex, asp.net-mvc

I am using javascript to validate email but its giving Parsing error in regex

```
var regex = new RegExp('^[a-z0-9]+([_|\.|-]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9]+([_|\.|-]­{1}[a-z0-9]+)*[\.]{1}(com|ca|net|org|fr|us|qc.ca|gouv.qc.ca)$', 'i');

Parser Error Message: "[" is not valid at the start of a code block. Only identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid.
```

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you try this way [Validate email address in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Comment: @HarishTalanki This SO answer is the generic way... may not be suited for OP's business rules.

Comment: @HarishTalanki tried that too.. again ended up with error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needed little bit googling. I was thinking MVC and NTire ASP.Net application need same Regular Expression, it was not the case, just replaced @ with @@ and it worked. :) thank for your time @Alex :)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex should look like this:

```
^[a-z0-9]+([_.-][a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9]+([_.-]­[a-z0-9]+)*\.(com|ca|net|org|fr|us|qc.ca|gouv.qc.ca)$
```

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/xK3cL4

Comment: @Imad Try to esacpe the `@` character: `\@`

Comment: Can you try same in your PC?

Comment: Its working in my colleague's system as well, what could be the problem? Believe me I am not harrasing anyone.

Comment: Is it due to I am using MVC

Comment: @Imad I don't know. Compare your configuration with your colleague's one.

Answer (score 0):

This regex is perfect and works fine for me.. try this.

```
/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\""))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
```

Comment: doesn't matter what regex I am using, there is always error after @ symbol.

Answer (score -3):

Can you provide more of the file containing this? If it is being processed through an engine that uses the @ tag to mark code (like Razor) it may be that this regex is causing a parse error on the server before the JavaScript is send to the client.

Razor already has @ tag, and if you need to embed @ characters (even in JavaScript regexes) that are passed to the server, you'd need to escape them using @@ instead of @, i.e., doubling them:

```
/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@@\"]+)*)|(\".+\""))@@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
```